# Prove that a closed ball is closed

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series

Prove that in $\[\vec{E}\]$ normed vector space
$\[B(\vec{x}, \varepsilon )\]$ is a closed set.

and $\[B'(\vec{x}, r)\]$ is an open set.

Fo the first part I created a sequence ($\[x_{n}\]
$) $\[\subset B(\vec{x},\varepsilon )\]
$ so I need to prove that $\[x_{n}\]
$ $\[\rightarrow x\]
 $ 
$\[\Rightarrow x \in B(\vec{x},\varepsilon )\]
$

Ok , I know that $\[x_{n}\rightarrow x \Leftrightarrow \left \| x-x_{n} \right \| \rightarrow 0\]
$
and that $\[\left \| \vec{x}-x \right \|\leq \varepsilon\]
$
I can transform this last inequality into $$\[\left \| \vec{x}-x +x + x_{n} \right \|\leq \varepsilon\]
$$ and then apply triangle inequality $$\[\left \| \vec{x}-x_{n} \right \|\leq \left \| \vec{x}-x\right \| +\left \| x- x_{n} \right \|\]
$$ and I know that $$\[\left \| x- x_{n} \right \|\rightarrow 0\]
$$
therefore I end up with the following inequality 
$$\[\left \| \vec{x}- x_{n} \right \|\leq \left \| \vec{x} - x\right \|\]
$$
but I don't know what to do next. I hope you can understand me...

Comment: Perhaps you should define what those sets are...

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: OK, done.${}{}$

Comment: What is the definition of a closed ball? Now pick an element (it should be obvious what this element will be like) and show that I can't find any open ball centered at that element that fits inside the closed ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $\overline{B(x,r)}$ be the closed ball around $x$ with radius $r$. If $(y_n)$ is a sequence in $\overline{B(x_0,r)}$ and $x_n\rightarrow y$, prove that for all $\epsilon>0:\|x-y\|\le r+\epsilon$ (use the convergence of $(y_n)$). Then it follows that $\|x-y\|\le r$.